# Is there a way to prevent taking damage in an electrical storm in Oblivia?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I was doing a quest in Oblivia when suddenly there was a lightning storm that was doing 50 damage every few seconds to me and my party. I fast traveled out of the area and came back to get rid of this annoying effect, but I was wondering if there was any way to prevent taking damage during this even and continue on my way.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

Heal up in cover and limit how much time you spend out of cover.

Use specific weather immunity armor mods.  These can be crafted.

Comment: There's at least one art (I believe it's Geolibrium) which nullifies weather. It's under the Galactic Knight line.

Comment: The specific augment for the storm in Oblivia is Thunderstorm Screen. There is a different augment for every type of weather effect. There are actually about a dozen different screen augments, along with one that I believe reduces but does not prevent the effects from all of them.